# Can't execute git commands in gitolite post-receive hook

Tags: git, hook, gitolite

I really can't figure out why this happens.

In my system I got the 'git' user with gitolite. All git repos, users and permissions for the repos work just fine, it seems gitolite is configured okay at least for a basic use.

Now I needed to set up a webserver on the machine with gitolite, I set up apache and, with the git user, I cloned a repo in the www directory so that I could access the files via browser.

No problems at all with the cloning, I also can manually do a `git pull` and git will pull from the repo.

The issue is when I try to automatically deploy the project to the www directory everytime a user pushes. I wrote a ~/.gitolite/hooks/common/post-receive script and the code is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
dir=/var/www/onlinerepo
if [ ! -d $dir ] ; then
        echo "the directory $dir does not exist"
        exit 1
fi

cd $dir
git pull
touch DONE
```

I also did a `gl-setup` to propagate the script to all the repositories.
When a user pushes, I'm sure the script is executed because I see the /var/www/onlinerepo/DONE file getting written, but no `git pull` is executed. I tried to see the output of the command doing a git pull >> OUTPUT, but it only creates an empty file.

If I execute the git pull command by command line, or even if I execute the post-receive script manually from command line, I see the usual "Already up-to-date" info message.

Am I doing something wrong? I really can't understand why `git pull` is the only command that fails in the script.

Comment: Perhaps `git pull` only writes to stderr, which you're not capturing. Try `git pull >> OUTPUT 2>&1` to get better diagnostic output.

Comment: Parenthetical and unrelated remark: The directory existence check isn't useful. If `cd` can't change into the supplied directory it'll tell you why. Your script can be rewritten to just `cd /var/www/onlinerepo && git pull && touch DONE` without any loss in functionality.

Comment: I'm quite new with everything here so thank you for your feedback!
I did as you said, and the error is: "fatal: Not a git repository: '.'"

I remembered getting that error from command line too while cloning, but I resolved specifing in a better way the git repo. I then changed `git pull` in the script code above with `git pull ssh://git@localhost/home/git/repositories/myrepo.git` but unfortunately I get the exact same error in OUTPUT. The command works fine from command line though.

Comment: I changed to `env -i git pull` and it seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved changing `git pull` with

```
env -i git pull ssh://git@localhost/home/git/repositories/myrepo.git
```

Comment: That works because `env -i` throws out all other environment variables.  But, that's a very big hammer (it throws out `$HOME` for instance).  The specific variable you need unset is `GIT_DIR`, so `unset GIT_DIR` before doing other git commands in other locations.